# Laplacian embedding of a graph with spherical constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, graph-laplacian

**TL;DR**

Is there any way to solve the following matrix equation

$$
(L - \Lambda)Y = 0
$$

where $L \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $Y \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$ (with $k < n$)
is a matrix of unknowns, $0$ is a zero matrix and **crucially** $\Lambda \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is a diagonal matrix of $n$ Lagrange multipliers $\lambda_i$?

**EDIT.** We can also assume that $L$ is symmetric.

---

I want to find a Laplacian embedding of a graph constrained so all nodes are positioned on a unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^k$. For simplicity, I assume that the graph is undirected, unweighted and has no self-loops.

Let $D$ be a diagonal matrix with node degrees along the diagonal, and $A = \{a_{ij}\}$ an adjacency matrix of a graph. Then we define the Laplacian matrix in the standard way as a symmetric matrix:

$$
L = D - A
$$

Now, I assume that all nodes are embedded in $\mathbb{R}^k$, so there is a matrix $Y \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$ of which $i$-th row gives the embedding coordinates of the $i$-th node of the graph.

So I try to find $Y$ by minimizing (squared) Euclidean distances between positions of connected nodes

$$
\sum_{i, j} a_{ij}||y_i - y_j||^2
$$
where $y_i$ is $i$-th row of $Y$ and subject to a constraint

$$
\forall_{i = 1, \ldots, n} \quad y_i^\top y_i = ||y_i||^2 = 1
$$
that is, I assume that all nodes are positioned on a unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^k$.

This is equivalent to the following constrained optimization problem using matrix notation

$$
\text{argmin}\text{Tr}(Y^\top L Y) \quad \text{s.t.} \quad y_i^\top y_i = 1 \quad (i = 1, \ldots, n)
$$

And this (I think) yields the following Lagranganian

$$
\begin{split}
\mathcal{L}
&= \text{Tr}(Y^\top L Y) - \sum_{i}\lambda_i(y_i^\top y_i - 1) \\
&= \text{Tr}(Y^\top L Y) - \text{Tr}(\Lambda YY^\top) + \text{Tr}(\Lambda)
\end{split}
$$
where $\Lambda \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is a diagonal matrix of individual Lagrange multipliers $\lambda_i$.

After differentiating with respect to $Y$ we get

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial Y}\mathcal{L} = 2LY - 2\Lambda Y = 0 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad (L - \Lambda)Y = 0
$$

This looks almost like a generalized eigenvalue problem, but $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix of unknown Lagrange multipliers.

Is there any way to solve such a problem?